# Useful book for PCB design

Tags: pcb, books

Im planning on buying a useful book for PCB design. Until now, I have these two options:

1. [High Speed Digital Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133957241)
2. [Circuit Designers Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750663707)

Both books seems OK, but the first one (the older one) is almost 2x more expensive.

Anyone with experience with one of two books or both? Would you recommend me another book? If so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: related: [Standard PCB Layout Book](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19458/standard-pcb-layout-book)

Answer (score 11):

My experience learning to lay out PCBs was that books are not helpful at the early stages. I'd start with free layout software like [Eagle](http://cadsoftusa.com/) and some good [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qG0O9LKH-_E).

Once you've laid out a couple of PCBs, the first book you linked to (High Speed Digital Design) is great-- the best reference on high speed design that I know of.

Comment: The tutorial videos are pretty good, and they do not take up an ungodly amount of time either. Excellent recommendation!

Answer (score 6):

plenty of good info here before you splash out on a book : http://alternatezone.com/electronics/pcbdesign.htm

Comment: Great resource Mike, great for starting out and definitely worth exhausting before moving on to advanced topics like high-speed digital layout, etc. Thanks for this, just what I was looking for to lay the foundation :)  I actually hear Dave's Australian accent when I read it. That's not weird, is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be a good one, judging from the author's articles and experience.

[EMC for Printed Circuit Boards by Keith Armstrong.](http://www.emcacademy.org/books.asp)

Answer (score 0):

One of the speakers at 2011 Freescale Technology Forum about High Speed PCB design gave a list of books to read, which I've listed on Amazon. Buy where you want to, it's just a convenient way to make lists like this. http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/2K083YEFHAFMY/ref=cm_sw_em_r_ws_Y1Ckob00BJCE8_wb